# JVM reuse in Hadoop mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, jvm, mapreduce

I have a mapreduce job, which takes a bunch of files on HDFS as input and generates some statistics. It runs well with no problem. However, when I set the jvm reuse properties "mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks" to "-1" or a small integer,e.g., 5, many mappers failed with the error message below

*ENOENT: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.open(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.createForWrite(SecureIOUtils.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.writeToIndexFile(TaskLog.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.syncLogs(TaskLog.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:229)*

Could anyone give me some hints about why it happened and how to fix this.

Thanks,

Comment: Curious - what's the value of this property when it runs 'with no problem'?

Comment: it is the default value, which is 1.

Comment: Which version and distro of Hadoop are you using?

Comment: What's the permissions on the log directory for each node running a task tracker? Do they match up with the hadoop runtime user?